# git list files that are fully staged

Tags: git, shell, command-line

is there a git command to list the files that have been fully staged?  I'm aware of git diff --name-only (with and without --cahced to see the unstaged/staged) but I'd like a list of files that are fully staged with no unstaged changes in them.

Comment: You want the set of files listed by `git diff --name-only --cached` but not listed by `git diff --name-only`?

Answer (score 3):

Use the comm program to filter the output of the file lists from the staging area and the working directory.

```
comm -23 <(git diff --cached --name-only) <(git diff --name-only)
```

And then alias it to `git fully-staged` or something if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want `git status --porcelain` for this.

```
git status --porcelain | grep '^[^ ] ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

From the [man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-status):

> --porcelain
>
> ```
> Give the output in an easy-to-parse format for scripts. This is similar to the short output, but will remain stable across Git
> ```
>
> versions and regardless of user configuration. See below for details.

Also the `Short Format` and `Porcelain Format` sections later in the document.